# undesired arrows at tips of a rotated parabola

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, rotating

I used `rotate=-90 degrees` to draw x=y^2+1, and the parabola acquired half-arrows at the ends and one at the vertex on the x axis.

```
\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (1,2);

\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (-1,2);
```

I'd like to understand why it happens and how to get rid of these arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\newcommand{\betkz}{\begin{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\etkz}{\end{tikzpicture} }
\def\myarrow{-{Latex[length=2mm]}}
    \begin{document}
\betkz
%dr%axis
\draw[\myarrow] (-2,0)--(3,0) node [right,scale=1.2] {$x$};
 \draw[scale=1,\myarrow] (0,-2)--(0,1.5) node [scale=1.2,right] {$ y$}; 

        \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
            \draw (\x,1pt) -- (\x,-3pt)
            node[scale=0.8,anchor=south east] {\x};
        \foreach \y in {-1}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[scale=0.8,anchor=north east] {\y}; 
\foreach \y in {1}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[anchor=east] {\y};




%draw graph


\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (1,2);

\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (-1,2);


 \fill [gray, opacity=0.2, domain=-1:1, variable=\x]
     (-1,-1 )
      -- plot ({\x}, {\x})
      -- (1, -1)
      -- cycle;

\fill [gray, opacity=0.2, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( 1,{sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- (2, 1)
      -- cycle;

\fill [white, opacity=1, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( {\x},{sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- (2, 1)
      -- cycle;


\fill [gray, opacity=0.2, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( 1,{-sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- (2, -1)
      -- cycle;

\fill [white, opacity=1, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( {\x},{-sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- (2, -1)
      -- cycle;


\draw[thick] (-1,-1)--(1,1);
\draw[thick] (1,1)--(2,1);
\draw[thick] (-1,-1)--(2,-1);

\draw[thin] (2,-1)--(2,1);
\draw[thin] (1,-1)--(1,1);
\node at (.5,-0.5) {$D$};


\node[scale=0.5,rotate=-40] at (1.5,-.5) {$x=y^2+1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. My guess would be that you have something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[->,..]`, but it's really impossible to say for sure from the information you have given. Can you make a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was filling the areas that added those arrows. Here is the code

Comment: `\newcommand{\betkz}{\begin{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\etkz}{\end{tikzpicture} }` - just to add some ekstra obscurity to the code, making it harder to read for those pesky code stealing terrorists.

Answer (score 1):

They're not really arrow tips, but you're  filling white over only part of the line. It's perhaps easier to see from  this image:

[image: bad filling]

which was made by the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (1,2);
\draw[ultra thick,rotate=-90] (0,1) parabola (-1,2);
\filldraw [fill=white, draw=red,ultra thin, opacity=1, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( {\x},{sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- (2, 1)
      -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You're covering up half the line with the filling, but because of the coordinates you've used, the end points are not handled good. One possible workaround would be to change the fill path to

```
\filldraw [fill=white, draw=red,ultra thin, opacity=1, domain=1:2, variable=\x]
     (1,0 )
      -- plot ( {\x},{sqrt(\x-1)})
      -- ++(0.1,0) % coordinate relative to the previous one
      |- cycle;
```

but I don't really think that's a good fix.

A somewhat better option is to move the drawing of the parabolas to after the filling, and change from `ultra thick` to `thick`.

But I would rather recommend to use a single path for both drawing and filling, as such:

```
\filldraw [fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2, draw=black,thick,samples=201]
  (1,0)
  -- plot[domain=1:2] ({\x},{-sqrt(\x-1)})
  -- (-1,-1)
  -- (1,1)
  -- (2,1)
  -- plot[domain=2:1] ({\x},{sqrt(\x-1)})
  -- cycle;
```

[image: output of code]

Other than that, I also made a new style for `myarrow`, instead of a macro. While both work for this case, if you add more options than just the arrow tip, the macro wont work.

And while entirely up to you, I'm not sure you really gain much from the `\betkz`/`\etkz` macros, so I would just use the original form.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
  myarrow/.style={-{Latex[length=2mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%dr%axis
\draw[myarrow] (-2,0)--(3,0) node [right,scale=1.2] {$x$};
 \draw[scale=1,myarrow] (0,-2)--(0,1.5) node [scale=1.2,right] {$ y$}; 

        \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
            \draw (\x,1pt) -- (\x,-3pt)
            node[scale=0.8,anchor=south east] {\x};
        \foreach \y in {-1}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[scale=0.8,anchor=north east] {\y}; 
\foreach \y in {1}
            \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) 
                node[anchor=east] {\y};

%draw graph

\filldraw [fill=gray,fill opacity=0.2, draw=black,thick,samples=201]
  (1,0)
  -- plot[domain=1:2] ({\x},{-sqrt(\x-1)})
  -- (-1,-1)
  -- (1,1)
  -- (2,1)
  -- plot[domain=2:1] ({\x},{sqrt(\x-1)})
  -- cycle;

\draw[thick] (-1,-1)--(1,1);
\draw[thick] (1,1)--(2,1);
\draw[thick] (-1,-1)--(2,-1);

\draw[thin] (2,-1)--(2,1);
\draw[thin] (1,-1)--(1,1);
\node at (.5,-0.5) {$D$};


\node[scale=0.5,rotate=-40] at (1.5,-.5) {$x=y^2+1$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AnnaMitina Consider accepting the answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left).